# how to send wall feed to facebook with image on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i"m trying to send to connected user wall feed with this method

```
public static void publishFeedDialog(final Context mContext) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "something");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                params.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);
                WallPostListener());

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(mContext,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Error posting story", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }}
```

what is the best and fast way to put image ?

in this method i dont see picture on the post .

how do i put image ? and can i avoid dialog before posting ?

Answer (score 0):

[Use This library](https://github.com/m3n0R/EasyFacebookConnect)

In this You will find every method of wall post.
With Image,ImageURL,Status etc.

Answer (score 0):

use face book sdk 3.0

and change that image into string..
and use this code

params.putString("picture", "ur image string");

Comment: "image string" - and what is that?